# Implementing APN's, get valid signing identity not found when install development profile?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

For APN's i'm following [raywenderlich tutorial from here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

i already have developer certificate installed in xcode, when i create AppId and configure it to push notification and create certificate(SSL) it adds a development certificate under certificate section..it's Ok.when i go to create provisioning profile it shows me only one certificate to choose(not newly created APN certificate). i created profile with that certificate but whenever i go to install it, it say "valid signing identity not found".
**Please note that I've installed both iOS Development and APNs Development iOS certificates in xcode.** I've searched similar question on stackoverfllow but still no luck.What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added the correct certificate(.p12) in you key chain access for the new provisioning profile created?

Comment: I forgot to add .p12 in keychain, as i mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution private key(.p12 file) was missing in keychain.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing wrong. But here is the general procedure:

1. Go to developer.apple.com and login
2. Go to Certificates, Identifiers and profiles
3. Create a certificates for iOS app development and APNS. For creating a certificate you need to upload a CSR (use Keychain Access to do this) from your Mac. Once you upload the CSR from your Mac, download the App and APNS certificates to your machine - If you don't upload the CSR from your machine, you will get a valid signing identity not found error.

Points to remember:

When creating APNS certificate, chooose the appropriate App ID. By choosing wrong ID push notifications wont work.

When creating the provisioning profile, choose the App certificate you created in the above steps.

Thats the gist, you should be able to figure out things I missed by following on screen instructions.

Comment: What is not working? You need to be more descriptive, share screenshots of the error if you can.